Email from script Sending as [object Object]
I'm unsure as to why this app script is sending an email with only [object Object] as the whole email?
I'm not smart enough to figure this out.
function scriptattempt() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let dataRange = sheet.getRange('A2:J');
  let data = dataRange.getValues(); 

  data.forEach((row, index) => {
    let [regnumber, siccode, sicname, companyname, e1, e2, filingdeadline, e3, email, emailSent] = row;
    if (!regnumber || !siccode || !sicname || !companyname || !filingdeadline || !email || emailSent === true) return;
    // Validate email address before sending the email

    if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
      Logger.log(`Invalid email address found in row ${index + 2,9}: ${email}`);
      return;
    }
let subject = `Upcoming Accounting deadline ${filingdeadline} for ${companyname}.`;
let body = `Dear Sir/Madam.<br><br>  

I hope this email finds you well.<br><br> 

We have been notified that your filing deadline is approaching and is due by ${filingdeadline}.<br><br> 

Text<br>
Text we are able to work with companies like you in the ${sicname} industry with efficiency and precision to ensure that you meet your deadlines on time.<br><br> 

Get in touch if you would like more information on how we can help you.<br><br> 

Warm Regards,`;

    
    // Send the email
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject, htmlbody: body});

    // Mark email as sent in column 
    sheet.getRange(index + 2, 10).setValue(true); // +2 because index is 0-based and data starts from row 2
  });
}

I've tried a few things but i cant seem to find what it isn't recognising

I think that in your script, htmlbody of MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject, htmlbody: body}); should be htmlBody. In this case, I think that no body is used and [object Object] is not shown. But you say this app script is sending an email with only [object Object] as the whole email. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this?

@Tanaike Edited Comment // The issue was no capital B in htmlbody.....// how do i mark your comment as the resolve

htmlBody not HtmlBody spelling counts in programming

Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From how do i mark your comment as the resolve, I posted it as an answer. You can accept it.

In your script, please modify htmlbody to htmlBody. So, please modify your script as follows.
From:
MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject, htmlbody: body});

To:
MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject: subject, htmlBody: body});

Reference:

sendEmail(message) of Class MailApp


Another problem is that the name of the subject property is missing.

@Wicket Thank you for your comment. At ES6, when the variable names of the key and the value are the same, they can be omitted. Ref For example, when it's const a = "sample", obj.a of const obj = { a } is sample.
